# Backing up GnuPG

Tags: encryption, gpg

I am not sure how to securly backup my .gnupg folder or to be specific my private key. I googled and found that people recommended just copying the whole .gnupg folder. Is there a safer way to Backup my private key, so that I can continue using it decrypting my files?

Comment: Copying the `~/.gnupg` directory is a bit clumsy, but should work for most purposes.  It's unclear what you mean by "securely" ...  You can export an individual set of private keys using `gpg -a --export-secret-key email@tld`  or an  individual key with `gpg -a --export-secret-key <keyid!>`  ... You could then use a program called `paperkey` to print out a paper copy of the private key and put the paper copy in a safe or safe deposit box.  However, the private key is only as secure as the platform the key is stored on and the passphrase.